# Amazon Kinesis with iOS

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-web-services, real-time, amazon-kinesis-firehose

Can iOS device send data to Amazon Kinesis Firehose Delivery System ? (the document has no api for iOS) If not, what product of AWS should I use to create a real time database to support iOS devices (as well as browsers).

Comment: Also, if the amazon cannot give out the solution, then what other services can I use, since I already select amazon's elastic beanstalk and s3.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[Amazon Kinesis Streams](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/streams/) is a great solution for realtime data streaming. Quote from its description:

Amazon Kinesis Streams enables you to build custom applications that process or analyze streaming data for specialized needs. Amazon Kinesis Streams can continuously capture and store terabytes of data per hour from hundreds of thousands of sources such as website clickstreams, financial transactions, social media feeds, IT logs, and location-tracking events. With Amazon Kinesis Client Library (KCL), you can build Amazon Kinesis Applications and use streaming data to power real-time dashboards, generate alerts, implement dynamic pricing and advertising, and more. You can also emit data from Amazon Kinesis Streams to other AWS services such as Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3), Amazon Redshift, Amazon Elastic Map Reduce (Amazon EMR), and AWS Lambda.

[Amazon Kinesis Firehose](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/firehose/) is similar to Kinesis Streams. It provides the easiest way to load data into Amazon S3 and Amazon RedShift.

Depending on what your use case is, pick one that fits you.

As for iOS SDK support, the AWS mobile SDK for iOS supports Kinesis Streams. See the developer guide of [Writing App Data to a Kinesis Stream](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/getting-started-kinesis.html). The SDK doesn't support Firehose at the moment. Please check back on [AWS Mobile SDK](https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdk/). If you need Javascript support in browsers, then there is [AWS SDK for JavaScript in the Browser](https://aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-browser/).

Comment: what is this http://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/getting-started-kinesis.html

Comment: That's Kinesis Stream, a sibling of Firehose, both of which belong to the Kinesis family. See https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/.

Comment: Thx, so is there other options on aws family which can update realtime? I actually dont need large data stream, firebase style is fine

Comment: I am not familiar with firebase, but I believe Kinesis should meet your need.

Comment: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Streams.html One more question, Is this what I am looking for too? Can DynamoDB + S3 satisfy the requirement?

Comment: for example, chatting : web to web, web to iOS, iOS to iOS

Comment: The question is too vague. There isn't one correct answer. Kinesis is good for streaming lots of data in realtime. Firehose allows you to load data into AWS storage. DynamoDB + S3 is a good combo in terms of high performance scalable database. Firebase is very handy for chatting apps. You need to evaluate all solutions before picking up one.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Realtime Cloud Storage](http://framework.realtime.co/storage/), an AWS DynamoDB powered cloud database with real-time data-sync between devices. It has iOS, Android, JavaScript (and more) SDKs.

Comment: Can it connect to EC2 ? if so, how should I do that ?

Comment: What do you mean with "connect to EC2"? Having an EC2 instance receiving the database updates?

Comment: I mean my web app is running and hosting on EC2. The database has to connect with the server.

Comment: Oh sure, no problem. Just use one of the available SDKs (nodejs, java, ...) and connect to the database from your EC2 instance. See this example https://github.com/realtime-framework/Storage/tree/master/todo-nodejs using nodejs.

Comment: Thx! i will try this one

Comment: Don't forget to create the data table with the key schema defined in https://github.com/realtime-framework/Storage/tree/master/todo-javascript#storage-table-definition

Comment: And you can try the data-sync with the live version at http://storage-public.realtime.co/samples/todo-lbl/index.html#/

Comment: Ooops, just noticed there was an error in the repo I sent you. Fixed now by commit https://github.com/realtime-framework/Storage/commit/4371d9aeba067da20802dd79a48f39364a4471c5

Comment: The business appears to be inactive.

Comment: Not true @aehlke, in fact the business is more active than ever ;)